# How to format the date using local culture using the blazor <InputDate /> tag

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using the  tag in my Blazor app. But how can i format the date using my own culture ?

```
            <InputDate class="form-control" @bind-Value="@ValidDate" @bind-Value:culture="nl-BE" @bind-Value:format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

[image]

regards
Dieter

Comment: Which preview version?  Localization was added to preview8, I think.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is `@bind-Value:format`, like so

```
@page "/"

<EditForm Model="@CurrentPerson">
    <InputDate @bind-Value="@CurrentPerson.DateOfBirth" @bind-Value:format="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
</EditForm>

@code
{
    Person CurrentPerson = new Person();
    public class Person
    {
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

There is also the option of using `bind-Value:culture`.

Comment: Using `@bind-Value:format="yyyy/MM/dd"` doesn't have any effect for me. The date in the input element is still formatted dd/MM/yy.

Comment: Tried using this and it doesn't seem to have any effect. I used @bind-Value:format="dd-MM-yyyy"

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to set format of **InputDate** or `<input type="date">`. It depends on browser settings. Users can change language of their browser. But you cannot change it from HTML. If you really need to customize format, you have to use **InputText** or `<input type="text">`. I would recommend to use some javascript library, for example [jQuery UI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats).

Answer (score 0):

The solution did not work for me. I got it working like this:

```
@code {
    private DateOnly? _geboortedatum;

    private string GeboortedatumFormatted
    {
        get => _geboortedatum?.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") ?? "";
        set
        {
            if (DateOnly.TryParse(value, out var newDate))
            {
                _geboortedatum = newDate;
            }
        }
    }
}

<div class="col-3">
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputDate @bind-Value="_geboortedatum" class="form-control d-none" />
        <InputText @bind-Value="GeboortedatumFormatted" class="form-control" id="geboorte-datum" placeholder="Geef geboortedatum." />
        <label for="geboorte-datum" class="form-label">Geboortedatum</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _geboortedatum" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**