# How to format <InputDate> to "dd/MM/yyyy" in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I'm new to Blazor and I'm working on a Blazor Webassembly project where I need to format the DateTime input as "dd/MM/yyyy".

I already tried this:

- [How to format the date using local culture using the blazor <InputDate /> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57508706/how-to-format-the-date-using-local-culture-using-the-blazor-inputdate-tag)
- [Set dd/mm/yyyy in a custom InputDate component instead of 01/01/0001 in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811444/set-dd-mm-yyyy-in-a-custom-inputdate-component-instead-of-01-01-0001-in-blazor) (This actaly is intresting, but thres nothing simplier?)
- [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format/9519493#9519493)

This is what I have:

```
<InputDate @bind-Value="@Model.Date1" class="form-control"/>
<InputDate @bind-Value="@Model.Date2" class="form-control"/>
<InputDate @bind-Value="@Model.Date3" class="form-control"/>
```

The Model:

```cs
public class Model
{
    public DateTime? Date1{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date1{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date3{ get; set; }
}
```

Also tried this:

```
<input type="date" @Bind="Model.Date1" @Bind:format="dd-MM-yyyy" class="form-control"/>
```

But nothing changed.

The [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwyXS.png)

The question is: How can I format the InputDate in "dd/MM/yyyy"?

Comment: Browsers display dates using local language/region settings - don't try to force a specific format yourself.

Comment: I agree with @MisterMagoo I live in Australia this is the default I see without doing anything in blazor. A lot of developers want to see them all and be selectable. The client/end user will just set the browser to their specific culture needs and thats it. Why force them to do it again inside your app?

Comment: It's not possible to change the date format because inputDate uses an html input type="date" which always uses the current locale.  Yet, there are open source and commercial components that will allow you to set the format, e.g., [SyncFusion DatePicker](https://www.syncfusion.com/blazor-components/blazor-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Your final attempt did not work because you used capital `B` instead of lowercase `b` and possibly because you also forced the `type="date"`. This is the correct usage:
`<input bind="Model.Date1" @bind:format="dd-MM-yyyy" class="form-control"/>`

Documentation for anyone else: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#format-strings

You can do something more complex using the @bind:set and @bind:get detailed on the same link.